# How to write code which performs calculations using the GPU?

Tags: gpu, gpgpu

We hear a lot about how certain types of calculation can be completed much more quickly by a GPU than by a CPU, but as a programmer I would have no idea how to force a calculation to be run in this way. Can anyone give a high-level explanation of how this is done?

I am aware that there are libraries which will do this 'by magic' but I would like to understand what they are doing behind the scenes. I'm pretty sure there isn't a `runOnGpu` flag that you can pass to low-level system calls, so what techniques are available?

Comment: Perhaps start by googling for "CUDA" or "OpenCL". There is a huge amount of reference material available which should answer your question...

Answer (score 0):

Need to rewrite your program. Use C++ AMP if you C++ or APARAPI if you Java.

Comment: As the question says: "I am aware that there are libraries which will do this 'by magic' but I would like to understand what they are doing behind the scenes"

Comment: Sorry if I didn't understand exactly your question. Well don't expect too much magic.. There is no royal road to efficient and portable and easy-to-write parallel code - at least I'm not aware of (but i might be wrong). Usually you choose 2 of 3. Coming back to original question, if you are interested in low-level GPU then study CUDA/OpenCL kernelsL. Even look at the generated assembly code to see 'behind the scenes', run kernel profilers (nvidia has nice tools). If there is a certain type of calculation you need (like fft, linear algebra) then trust the libraries offered by the vendor.